# dynamically populate paypal cart with all gridview contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, paypal

How do i dynamically populate paypal cart with all gridview contents with just 1 click of the add to cart button.

I think one should be able to iterate through the gridview creating a string of item I'd,  item name and item value and pass to paypal but I am unsure how to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the upload command to pass item details to PayPal, here's an example of post form https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/#id08A3F8090PF . You can set the item details base on the gridview contents.